# List all of the "A"'s in string

Tags: c#, string

I wanted to count all of the "A's" in a paritcular string.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace TESTING
{
    class Testing
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //ask user for the filename
            string userInput = fetchFileName("Enter the textfile you want to view: ");

            //test if the filename writes anything to console
            string fileContents = File.ReadAllText(userInput);

            string theFileContents = analyseFile(fileContents);
         //   Console.WriteLine(theFileContents);
            Console.ReadLine();

       }

        private static string analyseFile(string fileContents)
        {
            string str = fileContents;
            if (str.Contains("A"))                
            {
               Console.WriteLine("YES");

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("NO");
            }
            return str;
        }

        private static string fetchFileName(string askFileName)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(askFileName);
            string userAnswer = Console.ReadLine();
            return userAnswer;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're going to need to iterate the contents of the file somehow. Have you covered `for` loops yet? Serv's answer is easily adapted to a `for` loop since you are under the impression that you shouldn't use a `foreach`. However, the latter is definitely the preferred practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at LINQ. It allows to perform whole range of operations on any kind of collection. And a string is a collection of chars. Below an example how LINQ can make your life easier:

```
string text = "A sdfsf a A sdfsf AAS sdfA";
int res = text.Count(letter => letter == 'A');
```

What happens here is that you take `text` and provide a predicat saying that you want to take any variable `letter` from the string such that the `letter` is equal to char `A`. Then you want to count them.

Comment: Why did you provide oven-ready code? The asker clearly wished to learn not for a complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest ways is to iterate over all characters in your file and check if the letter is equal to the letter you want.

When you realize that a string is nothing more then an array of characters, you can do something like this:

```
public int LetterCount(string filename, char letter)
{
    int cnt = 0;
    string source = File.ReadAllText(filename);
    //Check every character in your string; if it matches increase the counter by 1
    foreach (char c in source)
    {
        if(c == letter)
        {
            cnt++;
        }
    }
    return cnt;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
int A_count = LetterCount(@"C:\test.txt", 'A');
```

Please note, that this code does not check, if the file actually exists. If you put in a wrong path, you end up with a `FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: Or shorter: `File.ReadAllText("Path").Count(c => c == 'A')`

Comment: I actually had to giggle, while reading the solution with Count @Ric.

Comment: @Ric If he's worried that `foreach` is too advanced for where he is in his class, `Count` is even worse.

Comment: @Rawling yeah I suppose so, but it just looks so neat

Comment: @Ric If the asker wants to learn these compact solutions will not do much for him.

Comment: @mg30rg agreed which is why my solution is a comment, rather than an answer as it's not teaching any fundamental concepts.

Comment: If the OP is asked to explain the lambda call with `.Count` in his class, he'll be in trouble I guess. It's easy. It's quick, but it would'nt help him understand the basics in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Foreach is just another type of loop. This could just as easily be done with a for-loop. The trick is to split the string up in individual characters that you can later compare.

I'm sure you will figure out how to implement this if I just set you on the right path:

```
string test = "My name is Isak";
char[] arrayOfChars = test.ToCharArray();
int count = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfChars.Length; i++)
{
     if (arrayOfChars[i] == 'a' || arrayOfChars[i] == 'A')
     {
          count++;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use linq

```
string text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
var count = text.ToLower().Where(x => x == 'a').Count();
Console.WriteLine(count);
```

But if you cannot use any advanced techniques you could do it like this:

```
string text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < text.Count(); i++)
{
    if (text[i] == 'a' || text[i] == 'A')
    {
        counter++;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(counter);
```

Answer (score 0):

try simple as

```
    string test = "ABBCDABNDEAA";

    int Count = test.Count(x => x == 'A');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `LINQ`, this can by really simple:

```
string myString = "ababsgsdfsaaaAA22bbaa";

var count = myString.ToLower().Count(c => c == 'a');

Console.Write(count);
```

Here we take the string and convert it to all lower case so that `A` and `a` will be counted together. Then we use the simple `LINQ` method `Count()` to count the number of `a` characters there are.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
        string stringValue = "Addsadsd AAf,,werAA";

        int qtdChar = stringValue.Count(x => x == 'A');
        int qtdCharInsensitive = stringValue.Count(x => x == 'A' || x=='a');
```

Answer (score -1):

If you do not want to use a foreach you could erase all the letter A's and compare the length difference.
A bit like this :

```
private static string analyseFile(string fileContents)
    {
        var strippedString = fileContents.Replace("A","");
        var count = fileContents.Length - strippedString.Length;

        return count.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Evil idea. It makes intent not obvious (similar to doing `i.ToString().Length == 1` check instead of `i > 0 && i < 10` :) ) and while it's *less code* it's unnecessarily slower.

Comment: His original question said a foreach was too complex so i figured a linq would also be too much. Performance wise i doubt there will be much difference. I even found a source claiming the replace method beats foreach & linq(although only by a small margin).